# Move folder matching a specific name into another folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

Could someone provide me with a simple example how to use App Script to move a folder matching a specific name (not ID) into another folder inside Google Drive?

I have searched the existing threads but couldn't find anything specific to matching a specific folder name.

Comment: There is code for copying a Google Drive folder on GitHub at link: [https://github.com/tanaikech/CopyFolder](https://github.com/tanaikech/CopyFolder)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you! Looking at the API, it seems to only be possible to copy a folder but not to move it. I guess, my question cannot be answered then.

Comment: Moving a folder just involves changing it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to move a folder to other folder in your Google Drive using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In your case, when the parent folder of the folder is moved, all files and sub folders in the folder can be moved. So the script can be simpler than the script for copying files. This has already been mentioned by [Cooper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064649/move-folder-matching-a-specific-name-into-another-folder#comment109778291_62064649).

The sample script is as follows. As the input values, the source folder name and destination folder ID are used.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, [Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) is used.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sourceFolderName = "###";  // Please set the source folder name.
  const destinationFolderId = "###";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  const src = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName);
  if (src.hasNext()) {
    const srcFol = src.next();
    srcFol.getParents().next().removeFolder(srcFol);
    DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId).addFolder(srcFol);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- When Drive API is used, the script becomes as follows.

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    const sourceFolderName = "###";  // Please set the source folder name.
    const destinationFolderId = "###";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

    const src = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName);
    if (src.hasNext()) {
      Drive.Files.patch({parents: [{id: destinationFolderId}]}, src.next().getId());
    }
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [removeFolder(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removefolderchild)
- [addFolder(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addfolderchild)

Comment: @orschiro Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.